# Uninstall all updates in a single click Windows XP SP 3

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, uninstall

I am using some old, outdated softwares which needs Windows XP SP 3.
Unfortunately, the ant-virus program turned the automatic updates ON and installed about 500 updates.
After which, none of the programs working fine.
My system restore is also corrupted.

Is there an easy way to uninstall all updates in a single click ( or using some commands)

Comment: It would probably be far easier to restore from the last disk image, or, if you do not have one, to completely reinstall XP. BTW, some software that runs on XP runs in wine on Linux; it might be worthwhile making a "Live CD" (or USB device) to test if you need XP. Making the bootable device takes less than an hour and you can use it immediately to test if the software runs in wine.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik  Wine is pretty good software. But my software is little bit big and it will take too much time to test all functionality using wine

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry to say , I have only one question `Is there an easy way to uninstall all updates in a single click ( or using some commands)` which is precise, vivid and clear.

Comment: Well there isn't a command that does that.  It might be more helpful to you and the community to solve the actual problem you have then provide an answer that indicates what you want isn't possible.

Comment: I would make the time investment to find and learn a new product that is supported by modern OS.  There is no way to uninstall that many updates easily, and in fact you could probably re-write the whole program in visual basic yourself before you got that many updates uninstalled.  Re-installing from scratch is the only way time effective way.  However, then you have to re-install all your programs.

Comment: I remember one of the old versions of Windows used to put a $Uninstall......  folder in the windows folder or maybe the system32 folder which would allow you to uninstall them 1 at a time.  You many or may not have those folders available to you.